How to apply all/any to functions with return type of Either?
This function will return an Either type. The String represent the error value ,and the Right/Bool represent normal boolean type that user care about
testPre :: Rational -> Rational -> Either String Bool
testPre a b
  | b == 0 = Left "Shouldn't be 0" 
  | a > b = Right True
  | a <= b = Right False

But what if I would like to test a list of numbers with a special any or all which works with Either String Bool ? Make any or all work in the context of Either ?
all (testPre 3)  [1,2]  =>  should be `Right True`
all (testPre 3)  [1,2,3]  =>  should be `Right False`

any (testPre 3)  [1,5]  =>  should be `Right True`
any (testPre 3)  [5,6]  =>  should be `Right False`

any (testPre 3)  [1,0,3]  =>  should be "Shouldn't be 0" 

Thank you

The monad instance of Either is essentially how all works.

What should happen if testPre returned Right False in some cases?

and the any works as the Semigroup instance.

(I fixed what I assume is a type of String for Left, as well as the spurious = before the guards.)

allM and anyM in the Either monad almost do what you want, except anyM short-circuits, so your last call sees that 1 passes and returns Right True.

Instead of all and any, you can use and and or in combination with traverse.
> and <$> traverse (testPre 3) [1,2]
Right True
> and <$> traverse (testPre 3) [1,2,3]
Right False
> or <$> traverse (testPre 3) [1,5]
Right True
> or <$> traverse (testPre 3) [5,6]
Right False
> or <$> traverse (testPre 3) [1,0,3]
Left "Shouldn't be 0"

(Though not defined this way, all and any can just be seen as combinations of and and or with fmap:
all p = and . fmap p
any p = or . fmap p

We're just replacing fmap with traverse, then mapping and/or over the result instead of applying them to the result.)

I don't really like the use of fmap or map in my analogy; it's really the fact that all/any take arbitrary foldables, which implement foldMap, not necessarily fmap. But the foldMap definitions of all/any involve custom monoids that don't really lend themselves to my transition to traverse. There's probably a better way of answering this question.
